# How can I center the title in Appbar.Header in react-native-paper?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, material-design

As you can see in the [docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/appbar-header.html), the default positioning for the title in react-native-paper is left-aligned. I've seen multiple questions and answers about how to implement a centered title both for Android Native as well as React Native's StackNavigator, but I am having no luck pulling off the same effect with `react-native-paper`.

So far I have tried using the `style` parameter in `Appbar.Header` to pass in `{ textAlign: 'center' }` or `{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }`, but nothing seems to work. I'm not very impressed with react-native-paper's lack of documentation on overrides, but I still hope there's a way to do what I'm looking for.

```
const styles = { header: { textAlign: 'center' }}

<Appbar.Header style={styles.header}>
  <Appbar.Action icon="close" onPress={() => this.close()} />
  <Appbar.Content title={title} />
  <Button mode="text" onPress={() => this.submit()}>
    DONE
  </Button>
</Appbar.Header>
```

Considering `title` accept a `node`, it can be used to display a react component.

How can I force center the title on all devices?

Comment: Try using `style` rather than `styles`

Comment: Should work with `flex-grow: 1; text-align: center;`. If you can provide a running example I can provide a method to center it.

Comment: Added an example. Tried using flexGrow and textAlign and still no luck :-/

Comment: Status update: I figured out that Android apps natively left-align, and that iOS apps natively center-align, and that React-Native follows these conventions by default. I'm happy with the default behavior and no longer need an answer to the questions, but I am still curious about the possibility of a solution because React-Native Paper's documentation currently leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`react-navigation` allows passing a component for `title` instead of a string, so we can do the same thing here:

I wrote an example that accepts a custom title component and can be used wherever we want:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Appbar, Button, Text } from 'react-native-paper';

const ContentTitle = ({ title, style }) => (
  <Appbar.Content
    title={<Text style={style}> {title} </Text>}
    style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
  />
);

const App = () => (
  <Appbar.Header> 
    <Appbar.Action icon="close" onPress={() => this.close()} />
    <ContentTitle title={'Title'} style={{color:'white'}} />
    <Button mode="text" onPress={() => this.submit()}>
      DONE
    </Button>
  </Appbar.Header>
);

export default App;
```

You can check: https://snack.expo.io/r1VyfH1WL

Answer (score 6):

There is 2 approach for this.

First,
The `Appbar.Content` has `marginLeft` applied to it. So, you just need to set the `marginLeft` to 0.

```
<Appbar.Header>
  <Appbar.BackAction />
  <Appbar.Content title='Title' style={{ marginLeft: 0 }} titleStyle={{ marginLeft: 0 }} />
  // Put empty action here or any action you would like to have
  <Appbar.Action/>
</Appbar.Header>
```

Sadly, this approach only allowed one menu action on the right. (or have an equal amount of actions both left and right, but I think only one menu action will be on the left side, that is back button)

Second, make the `Appbar.Content` has an `absolute` position. And yes, keep the `marginLeft` to 0.

```
<Appbar.Content title='Title' 
  style={{ marginLeft: 0, position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: -1 }} 
  titleStyle={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
```

We need to set the zIndex to -1 (or lower) so the button/menu action is clickable. This way, you can have more than one menu actions.

The first way is simple but limited, while the second way is powerful but more code to write.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `titleStyle` instead of `style` to center the text. The below code is working for me.

```
<Appbar.Header>
  <Appbar.Content titleStyle={{textAlign: 'center'}} title="Centered Title" />
</Appbar.Header>
```

There is also a similar `subtitleStyle` for styling the subtitle. [Check the docs for more info](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/appbar-content.html).

Comment: It does not work. At least not for all. It is **unecessary on iOS** *(default and can't be changed (eg: no right or left value))*, it **work on web**, and it **does not display at all the title on Android unless it is text**. It can work on android only if text but `title` props is supposed to accept more than text (a `node`).  How can I do the same with an Svg component (which is a node) as a `title` ? This makes it disappear on Android, so don't use  `titleStyle={{textAlign:'center'}}`

Answer (score 1):

For 'react-native-paper', this snippet worked for me:

```
<Button    
style = {{justifyContent: 'center'}}
>
Press
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should align both text/node title:

```
    <Appbar.Content
      title={<Text>title</Text>}
      style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
    />
```

See https://snack.expo.io/rJUBIR6lU

Comment: It also does not work on android if we use a svg as react component. I have a svg logo I need to center on all device. We can't use text.

Comment: That doesn't look like centered to me: https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/bold-tortillas

Comment: Can you show a screenshot showing what you are seeing and why that's not centered?

Comment: Web: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1866564/72712378-7e1dae00-3b9d-11ea-87f5-194cba2944ce.png

Comment: Android: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1866564/72714228-f3d74900-3ba0-11ea-8489-29dfb8c9a169.png

Comment: iOS: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1866564/72714250-ff2a7480-3ba0-11ea-9dbf-9ece0069a5be.png

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Appbar>
    <Appbar.Content titleStyle={{alignSelf: 'center'}} title='something'  />
  </Appbar>
```

Comment: It's better to always provide some explanation to the code, it helps the community and attract upvotes